formalize "there exists a function f such that f(a)=b" into first-order formula
I want to know how to formalize the sentence "there exists a function f such that f(a)=b" into a first-order formula. It should not be
$\exists f f(a)=b$
because first-order logic does not allow quantifying over functions.
Update:
Maybe we need to restrict the first-order language to that for ZFC which has no other relation symbols but $\in$, to make the "existence" of f more obvious.

The way to formalize it, is to use formally define all of the relevant defined terms in terms of first order formula, and then just put them together. So, define what it means to be an unordered pair, ordered pair, relation, and then just write out the definition of a function. If you want to see it in terms of first order formula, just unravel all of the defined terms. Hint: f(a) = b is a shorthand for (a,b)∈f

Updated version
As you are aware, there is no quantification of function symbols in first-order logic.
Thus, the formula $\exists f (f(a)=b)$ is second-order.
In the language of first-order set theory, functions are simply sets.
Thus, the statement will be: $\exists f \ \forall x [x \in f \leftrightarrow \exists a \exists b (x = \langle a, b \rangle)] \land \forall a \forall b \forall c (\langle a, b \rangle \in f \land \langle a, c \rangle \in f \to b=c]$

First-order logic does not allow quantifying over binary predicates either.

Your formula looks good in that I can see how the "existence" of f appears. But it is a little different than ordinary definition of function which involves a domain  and a co-domain.

You can define a function as the relation between elements where $f(x,y)\iff f \text{ maps } x \text{ to } y.$ Then $f$ is a binary predicate and the formula  expresses the existence of such a relation that satisfies $f(a,b)$ . With that in mind we have
$$\forall x\exists y(R(x,y))\to(f(a,b)\land\forall z(R(x,y)\to z=y)))$$
This asserts the existence of a binary relation and that $\forall x\exists!y$ such that $f(a)=b$

First-order logic does not allow quantifying over binary predicates either.

In this statement , by removing $\exists R$ you end up with an equivalent statement. Thanks for pointing it out though.

But I cannot see how the "existence" of f appears in your formula.

In the context of a formal proof, you could introduce the predicates $F, D$ and $C$  in a premise as follows:

$\forall x:[D(x) \implies \exists y:[C(y) $ $\land ~[F(x,y) \land \forall z:[C(z) \implies [F(x,z) \implies z=y]]]]]$

Where the predicate $D$ is the domain of the functional relation $F$, and the predicate $C$ is the codomain.
Being a premise, the existence of predicates $F, D$ and $C$ is provisionally assumed only up until that premise discharged. In FOL, however, no formal generalization on these predicates is possible at any point.

I cannot see how the "existence" of f appears in your formula. Can you formalize it in the first-order language for ZFC which has no other relation symbols but $\in$? Maybe that would make the "existence" of f  more obvious. Another related question is if the existence of a function implies the existence of its domain and co-domain, i.e., informally, $\exists f f(a)=b \leftrightarrow \exists f \exists D \exists C a\in D \land b\in C \land f(a)=b$?

In algebra and analysis, for example, you can only formally prove the existence of a function by constructing that function from given sets by using the axioms of set theory. If you are restricted to only predicate logic, you can only examine the properties of functional relations that are provisionally assumed, not proven to existence, as above.
